# Android studio not loading design view for xml files that includes "FragmentContainerView" on Apple M1 chip

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, apple-m1

All xml files are loading just fine unless it includes "FragmentContainerView" element. commenting out the element solving the problem.

it's not giving any errors, actually the screen is black and clicking on a random point of the design view will highlight the code line of the element even if its not showing. so it's there but just not showing.

MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020) 16GB
macOs: Monterey 12.6

Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1

I've tried invalidating caches. playing with vmoptions. checking updates of android studios.

Fragment example.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordianatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/newbackround"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
        android:text="@{viewModel.communityGroupModel.refused.toString()}"
        android:textColor="@color/black1b1d20"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_20"
        tools:text="27" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/eventPostFragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_12"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: More context and code would be nice. Did you use it inside Activity or how are you using it?

Comment: Edited with code example. @LawrenceGimenez

Comment: It's either Invalidate Caches -> check all optional -> invalidate and restart. 
Or restart the laptop itself also using same macbook.

Comment: Unfortunately it donest solve the problem. i'm having it since day one it's been one month of using now.